# Rails 4 - Javascript doesnt work unless its put within script tags on page

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, sprockets

I have an app where Im using a lot of unobtrusive javascript to append rails partials to my page.

The trouble I have is this: javascript if placed in the assets directory wont work.

In Chrome dev tools I can see its loaded but, nothing happens.  In my Coffeescript file I've used the DOM ready alternative for turbolinks found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18770589/1789778).  But this has no effect.

Whats strange is: If I place the script within script tags on the loaded partial then it works.

For example: this coffeescript file wont function if the partial containing the tabs is loaded after the javascript is loaded.

```
var ready;
ready = function() {

    $('tab').click ->
        $('.tab').removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");
        panel = $(this).attr("data-panel")
        $('.panel').hide();
        $('#' + panel).show();

};

$(document).ready(ready);
$(document).on('page:load', ready);
```

Whereas this script placed at the bottom of the page with the tabs does work.

```
<script>
        $('.tab').click(function() {
            $('.tab').removeClass("active");
            $(this).addClass("active");
            var panel = $(this).attr("data-panel")
            $('.panel').hide();
            $('#' + panel).show();
        });
</script>
```

My question is this: First why is this happening? Second, is there a way to overcome this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the . from $(.tab).click listener.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my error.  However, even if I place the script-tag JS within a JS file and load it via the asset pipeline the same results apply.

Comment: Why are you calling both $(document).ready(ready) and
$(document).on('page:load', ready)? You might possibly be triggering the listener twice.

Comment: If you add a console message into your ready function, does it appear?